# Dojo: adding a button dynamically

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to add a dijit button to a node but it is failing with

> Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child
>   element is null.

The code is

```
var output = dom.byId(this.baseClass + 'displayValues');
var btnDelete = new Button({ label: "Delete" }, "btnDelete");
btnDelete.startup();
domConstruct.place(btnDelete, output);
```

The output element is definitely valid as I can add a bunch of span tags to it if i want with the same sort of code

I can also add buttons with this kind of code

```
var node = domConstruct.toDom('<li>' + name + '|' + value + '<button type=\"button\" OnClick=\"this._removeItem(\'' + name + '\');\">X</button></li>');
```

but in this case it can't find the on click method with this, parent or no modifier. In any case the document says not do so this kind of thing because of memeory leaks

Does anyone have any pointers to what might be going wrong.

Many Thanks for any all help

Comment: you should not have to do the domConstruct command.  the second argument of new Button is the location of the element to place the button.  http://jsfiddle.net/N2Yjt/1/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You should repost as an answer so I can upvote you. Cheers

Comment: In addition to all the other answers, domConstruct.place is looking to place a node and not an actual widget. So domConstruct.place(btnDelete.domNode, output); should also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second argument to the Button constructor may be either ID of html element, or DomNode object.

This is how I use the second option, with dynamically created nodes.

```
define(["dojo", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/query", 
function(dojo, dom, domStyle, domClass, domConstruct, query) {
    var buttons = dom.byId('my-buttons');
    var buttonNode = domConstruct.toDom('<button type="button" class="button delete-button"></button>')
    buttons.appendChild(buttonNode)
    var button = new Button({label: "Delete" }, buttonNode);
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. It works. My Dojo is clearly weak (just starting) so learning required i think

Comment: @CrabBucket hard way, because there's not so much documentation, tutorials and examples for Dojo.

Answer (score 1):

The domConstruct command is not needed, the second argument of new Button is the location of the element to place the button.

```
var btnDelete = new Button({ label: "Delete" }, <idOfContainerElement")
```

[jsfiddle.net/N2Yjt/1](http://jsfiddle.net/N2Yjt/1)